# How to open the My Files folder in Android Programatically (using Intent)?

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I am using the below code which opens up the Gallery, Music Player, Dropbox and Contacts, i want the My Files folder to get open programatically, please let me know if there are any specific intent parameters i need to pass to get the File Manager open.

if it is not possible through intent then please give me a snippet or an hint to open the My Files folder programatically.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "View Default File Manager");
startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to file the files.

```
int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE=1;            
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                 
intent.setType("file/*");              
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

this  will help you to browse the files from your storage.

Comment: this code help me... but i want view only .pdf extension files in my file explore.
How it is possible?

Comment: it will help to open custom file only, there is table there to see http://indyvision.net/android-snippets/android-using-intents-open-files/

Answer (score 2):

Its best that you include a library in your project which handles this scenario.

[This](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) worked for me:

This library shows the list of third-party apps. It also has its own file browser for selecting files.

Answer (score 1):

Bad thing is, most Android distributions may or may not ship with a file manager, and even so, may be not with the one which handles `CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE`.

So, you are left to create your own file picker activity. Luckily there are many ready made ones available:

http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/android/

Comment: CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE is programmer defined, it is not an Android defined constant, right?

Comment: @Radu All System defined actions are defined as `ACTION_` constants in `Intent` class. `CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE` is not there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open samsung My Files application try this below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");              
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

Comment: What if it is not a Samsung? Like kinda of China phone?

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer The best bet would to make "chainable" intents, requesting the PackageManager if the Intent is resolvable. E.G: `if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())==null){intent=nextIntent;...}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specifically mention the package name of the explorer application. Please find the example below to open a specific folder in ES Explorer.

```
 public void openfolderInexplorer(String path){
  Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.estrongs.android.pop");
 if (intent != null) {
           // If the application is avilable
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Play store to install app
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + 
            "com.estrongs.android.pop"));
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this below code. if any file manager available , then it will pop up in a form of menu to choose appropriate for the user.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

Comment: How we can use it to open specific file only? I mean If I want to open the file of ".dco" extension, how it would be?

Comment: I found this link,it will help to open custom file only, there is table there to see http://indyvision.net/android-snippets/android-using-intents-open-files/

Comment: CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE: you must define this yourself for your own reasons. It does not do that the question asks for.