# File browser option (HTML5 apps) does not show default file explorer

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonejs

I am developing an android application with **PhoneJS and Cordova**.

I tried to use `<input type="file">` but when i hit "choose file" in my phone, the file browser option appear (**list of file explorers i.e.  Drop box, g Drive, ES file explorer, Office Suit, Photos, Gallery, Sound picker** ) but not show the default file explorer ("My File" in android).

How to call (**android**) default file explorer with web base language i.e. JavaScript, Jquery, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you made this fix on your local device, it seems (from  [How to open the My Files folder in Android Programatically (using Intent)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097763/how-to-open-the-my-files-folder-in-android-programatically-using-intent)) that most Android devices ship with different file choosers. You're best off having an in-app chooser or settling with whatever your consumer already has on their devices (My Files doesn't show up on my phone for example).

You can try the following.

http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/android/