# How to programatically open a folder in android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application which opens folders,

My question is how can I open a folder programmatically in Android? .

I tried all the solutions available in stack-overflow and searched in Google but I couldn't find a solution. Can someone please provide me an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define what you mean by opening a folder.  Get a list of files in it?  Something else?

Comment: @GabeSechan he says open a folder.  what it matters what is inside the folder. I think he need to content to display inside the folder like when we click on a folder in general.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/filebrowserandroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/moo/android/filebrowser/FileBrowser.java?r=9

Comment: I mean when i set uri path for a specific folder like "Download" then my application can open the folder ? , i'm sorry for ambiguous

Comment: @SMK yes this what i mean in my question, thank you

Comment: You didn't google it. I mean, seriously. A simple search for 'Android Directorychooser code example' resulted in thousands of sample codes.

Comment: @Saleh_IB you may need to refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097763/how-to-open-the-my-files-folder-in-android-programatically-using-intent?rq=1 this might be what you need

Comment: @Wamasa, I google it before i post my question here, and there are in stackoverflow much questions like my questions but i can't find anything. So i post my question

Comment: @Saleh_IB ok, heres what you need [link](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser)

Comment: Ok @Wamasa thanks a lot for your help and all replies, i will try the all suggestions and i will post here what can i do for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can open folder with use of following code

```
File file = new File(path);
        Uri uri_path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension
                (MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path));


        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType(mimeType);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri_path, mimeType);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can it open any folder ? Did you check on Samsung also ?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Samsung no idea bro..by the way how are you bro?